# Xamarin.Forms correct way of Binding in ResourceDictionary Controls

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm having problems getting this to work.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ViewCell x:Key="Separator">
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
    </ViewCell>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The class Option contains a property named Title which is set to whatever text. However the following code is not working. No text appears in the label. Text just stays "null". What am I doing wrong - how can I set the Binding correctly?

```
if (Resources.ContainsKey("Separator"))
{
    var cell = Resources["Separator"] as Cell;

    if (cell != null)
    {
        cell.BindingContext = option;

        section.Add(cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? It's kind of uncommon to have a cell in a resource dictionary in XAML and then add it via code and use bindings. Maybe some more context would help?

Comment: Sure, so my idea is to have a number of different ViewCells (some containing only text, some checkboxes etc.) which I can add to a TableView depending on a given "option.Type" (which I have simplified above to "Separator"). My thought is to define them in XAML (as are most of my controls) and then use these in code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects in a `ResourceDictionary` are created only once, and their instances are shared everytime you use them. As `ViewCell` and `Binding` can not be reused, this is unlikely to work.

What you **can** define in the `ResourceDictionary` is a `DataTemplate` containing the `ViewCell`, and in that case, it can be shared as the `DataTemplate` content will be recreated for each usage.

Comment: I wrote in the comment above that I have a number of different ViewCells. I tried DataTemplates, but got stuck when trying to create these from code without kind of TableView.ItemTemplate or similar. When it comes to a single template I agree, this is easy to achieve, but how about multiple?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I was able to solve it with a DataTemplateSelector: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/selector/